Saying Asher Yatzar at night
If one wakes up in the middle of the night to use the bathroom

Does he need to wash negel vaaser before saying Asher Yatzar?
Does he need to brush his teeth to remove bad breath before saying Asher Yatzar?



Does he need to wash negel vaaser before saying Asher Yatzar?

If one is planning on going back to sleep:

If one wakes up in the night to go to the bathroom, one should wash one's hands without a bracha and should not make Birchot HaTorah. After going to the bathroom, go back to sleep, and upon waking up in the morning wash with a bracha before saying Birchot Hatorah as usual 1 (source)

1 Or Letzion (vol 2 chap 1:2) writes that if one is going back to sleep and one only woke up temporarily to go to the bathroom, one should make the Netilat Yadayim without a bracha.
See also:

One should not delay the blessing of Asher Yatzar until morning, and it is therefore to be said after each time you use the bathroom in middle of the night.
The order you should follow is such: One who wakes up in middle of the
night to use the bathroom should first wash his hands next to his bed
before walking, then use the bathroom, then wash his hands again
afterwards, and then immediately recite Asher Yatzar. If it is already
past midnight, you may choose to already wash hands after the bathroom
like you would by the second morning washing and already recite the
blessing of Al Netilas Yadayim, and then immediately after recite
Asher Yatzar. If you plan to return to sleep, however, then you don’t
have to do so and may simply wash after the bathroom without any
blessing, and recite Asher Yatzar. If, however, it is already past
daybreak, then you should specifically do this order even though you
still plan to return to sleep, and therefore you should wash hands
after the bathroom and recite the blessing of Al Netilas Yadayim, and
then immediately after, recite Asher Yatzar and Elokaiy Neshama, and
you may then return to sleep.


With regard to brushing teeth, I am unsure yet. The Shulchan Aruch says that one should brush ones teeth in the morning before prasing Hashem OC 4:17 and here. We praise Hashem during Asher Yatzar, but I don't know what the halacha is regarding brushing ones teeth when waking up in the night, before going to the restroom, and saying asher yatzar. Maybe someone else could help.
